# Setting UITapGestureRecognizer for custom UIView inside loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a view controller which contains nested `UIView`. I would like to add a tap listener for each subview I'm adding. But I caught a `SIGABRT` error when I tap the subview.

Here is my code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set container
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 320, 420)];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    //create new subview within container. I call it "card"
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        //create card
        UIView *card = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35 + (65 * i), 300, 45)];
        card.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        //set tap event with action selector = cardRowTapped
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardRowTapped)];
        [card addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        //add subview
        [container addSubview:card];
    }

    //add subview to self
    [self.view addSubview:container];

}
```

and here is my tap handler code

```
- (void) cardRowTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    NSLog( @"hello");
}
```

Console output:

> 2012-10-03 13:23:37.173 MyProject[5167:707] -[MyViewController
>   cardRowTapped]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2cd810
>
> 2012-10-03 13:23:37.179 MyProject[5167:707] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MyViewController cardRowTapped]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x2cd810'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0x314b888f 0x377f6259 0x314bba9b 0x314ba915 0x31415650 0x30c45637 0x30bd5d65 0x30e06479 0x30b51f55
>   0x30b50aa3 0x30b5d7e9 0x30b5d627 0x30b5d1f5 0x30b43695 0x30b42f3b
>   0x3348922b 0x3148c523 0x3148c4c5 0x3148b313 0x3140e4a5 0x3140e36d
>   0x33488439 0x30b71cd5 0x76e8d 0x76e28) terminate called throwing an
>   exception(lldb)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you provide the error in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method requires a member variable which is passed by the gesture, so change the tap gesture method like below,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardRowTapped:)];
```

and check out it should work, one more thing if you are not using ARC, then release the objects after their usage.

Comment: Thank you. this is working. you saved my life. but what does `:` in cardRowTapped: means?

Comment: if ur methods have/require parameters, then in ur selectors you must provide `:` after the method name..

Answer (score 0):

try this code when you add gesture give the delegate like bellow..

```
UIView *card = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 35 + (65 * i), 300, 45)];
        card.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        //set tap event with action selector = cardRowTapped
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardRowTapped:)];
        [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [tap setDelegate:self];
        [card addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [tap release];
        //add subview
        [container addSubview:card];
```

and give the Delegate in .h file like bellow..

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<
UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{
//.....
}
```

i hope this help you...

:)

Comment: I still get the same error with this, And i'm using ARC. so i can't do the [tap release]. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code:

```
//set tap event with action selector = cardRowTapped
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cardRowTapped:)];
        [card addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

only difference is:

```
@selector(cardRowTapped:)
if you have the method with parameter then ":" should be there.
```